# How to access $vuetify instance in setup function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

Is there a way to get access to $vuetify (and any other added global) in the setup function?
Is there a way for composables to access it?

```js
  ...
  setup() {
    const { isDesktop } = $vuetify.breakpoints.mdAndUp; // <=== how to get $vuetify
    return { isDesktop };
  },
```

Comment: The docs have now been updated with how to do this for Vuetify 3: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform/#usage

Answer (score 9):

Composable to get vuetify instance:

```js
// useVuetify.ts
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export function useVuetify() {
  const instance = getCurrentInstance()
  if (!instance) {
    throw new Error(`useVuetify should be called in setup().`)
  }
  return instance.proxy.$vuetify
}
```

Import it in your component:

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script lang="ts">
import { useVuetify } from './useVuetify'
import { computed } from 'vue'

/*...*/
  setup() {
    const vuetify = useVuetify()
    const isDesktop = computed(()=>vuetify.breakpoints.mdAndUp)
    return { isDesktop }
  },
/*...*/
</script>
```

If you are using Vue <= 2.6.14 + `@vue/composition-api` instead of Vue 2.7, replace `'vue'` with `'@vue/composition-api'`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for posting this. This composable is a perfect bridge for projects where you want to use an existing Vuetify codebase, but want to smooth out the eventual migration to Vue 3/Vuetify 3 by working in the Composition API now.

Comment: @PhilAlegret I made a template with Vuetify 2 + Vue 2.7, you can find more good practices of bridge https://github.com/kingyue737/vitify-admin

Comment: Thank you for sharing this repo @yue-jin, great examples throughout.

Comment: Vuetify 3 offers [https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform/] useDisplay composable if you are interested for breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

As @Lagamura mentioned in the comments, this can be achieved with Vuetify 3 using [`useDisplay()`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform/#usage).

E.g.

```
const {mobile} = useDisplay();

console.log(mobile.value);
```

Comment: NOTE: Using `useDisplay()` like this without destructuring won't preserve reactivity. It is better to destructure like `const { mobile } = useDisplay()` - see https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#conventions-and-best-practices

Comment: Thanks for bringing this feature to my attention in the first place! I've also added a link to the docs in your answer